# How to use date picker in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using laravel 5.8 and i want to include date picker. I tried many ways but did not work anyone for me. Can anyone please help me to get out of this trouble.

**Registration.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12 form-group dates">
    <label>Joining Date *</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control air-datepicker" name="Joining_Date" autocomplete="off" id="usr1">

</div>
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('/css/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}">
    <script>

      $(function() {

       $( "#usr1" ).datepicker({
       format: "mm/dd/yy",
       weekStart: 0,
       calendarWeeks: true,
       autoclose: true,
       todayHighlight: true,
       rtl: true,
       orientation: "auto"
       });

   });
   </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following code it should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="bsdp-css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
                        format: "mm/dd/yy",
                        weekStart: 0,
                        calendarWeeks: true,
                        autoclose: true,
                        todayHighlight: true, 
                        orientation: "auto"
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I put my existing code before the closing body tag instead closing head tag. By the way thanks.